# how can we create cloudant service of bluemix in jenkins using ibmcloud? Is ibmcloud plugin available for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ibm-cloud, cloudant

what's the process of create cloudant service that is resource group specific in jenkins. how can we made connection in jenkins of resource group of bluemix. I had tried and create service using cloud foundry plugins that is org and space specific  but resource group services is not created Please guide